# How to get app installation directory using phonegap

Tags: cordova

I want to write something on my app installation directory using phonegap.

I checked the API, I think it doesn't have a way to get app installation directory. At max I found fileSystem.root which will give root directory.

like this:
http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/files.html

Please help me out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Similar question has already been asked 2 or 3 times today...
You can't write neither to "app installation directory" nor to internal assets folder.

But you can write (and download) files to application data folder.

Docs about it: http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/2.9.0/cordova_file_file.md.html